# STM32F103 DAC and ADC won't run concurrently

Tags: c, arm, stm32, adc, digital-analog-converter

I have a thread set up to constantly read 18 ADCs across ADC1 and ADC3 and fill them into arrays.

```
void TSK_AdcSensor(void const *argument){

ADC1_Configuration();
ADC3_Configuration();

//Clear the ADC value registers
for (i=0; i<MAX_ADC1_CHANNELS; i++){
    adc1Sensor[i] = 0;
}  

for (i=0; i<MAX_ADC3_CHANNELS; i++){
    adc3Sensor[i] = 0;
}

while(1){
    //Start ADC1 software conversion
    ADC_SoftwareStartConvCmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

    //Start ADC3 software conversion
    ADC_SoftwareStartConvCmd(ADC3, ENABLE);

    //wait for DMA to finish:
    result1 = osSignalWait(ADC1FINISHED, osWaitForever);
    result2 = osSignalWait(ADC3FINISHED, osWaitForever);


    for(i=0; i<MAX_ADC1_CHANNELS; i++){
        adc1Sensor[i] += ADC1_SensorValues[i];
    }

    for(j=0; j<MAX_ADC3_CHANNELS; j++){
        adc3Sensor[j] += ADC3_SensorValues[j];
    }


    ADCcounter++;


    if(ADCcounter>=100){
        for(i=0; i<MAX_ADC1_CHANNELS; i++){
            adcSensor[i]=(float)adc1Sensor[i]/ADCcounter;
            adc1Sensor[i]=0;
            //printf("\n\radc1[%i]=%.1f\n\r",i,adcSensor[i]);
        }
        for(j=0; j<MAX_ADC3_CHANNELS; j++){
            adcSensor[j+MAX_ADC1_CHANNELS]=(float)adc3Sensor[j]/ADCcounter;
            adc3Sensor[j]=0;
            //printf("\n\radc3[%i]=%.1f\n\r",j,adcSensor[j+MAX_ADC1_CHANNELS]);
        }
        ADCcounter=0;
    }

    osDelay(5);

}//end while(1)
}
```

I also have a function that sets one of two output DAC channels upon receipt of the desired setting from the usart

```
void RegSetDAC(u8 reg_select, u16 reg_value)
{  
DAC_Configuration();

if(reg_select == 1)
{
    if(reg_value > 1250)
    printf("\n\r *E*0** regulator 1 out of range\n\r");

    else
    {                    
        dac_value1=0;  
        dac_value1=EPC1(reg_value);
        osDelay(100);
        // Set DAC Channel2 DHR12Rregister
        DAC_SetChannel2Data(DAC_Align_12b_R,  dac_value1);
        // Start DAC Channel2 conversion by software
        DAC_SoftwareTriggerCmd(DAC_Channel_2, ENABLE); 
        printf("*E*%u*%u**\t\n\r  " ,reg_select,reg_value);
    }
}

else if (reg_select == 2)
{  
    if(reg_value > 100)
        printf("\n\r *E*0** regulator 2 out of range\n\r");

    else
    {
            dac_value2=0;
        dac_value2=EPC2(reg_value);
        osDelay(100);

        // Set DAC Channel1 DHR12R register
        DAC_SetChannel1Data(DAC_Align_12b_R, dac_value2);
        // Start DAC Channel1 conversion by software
            DAC_SoftwareTriggerCmd(DAC_Channel_1, ENABLE);
            printf("*E*%u*%u**\t\n\r  " ,reg_select,reg_value);
        }
    }  
//      printf("*%f*%f**\t\n\r  " ,dac_value1,dac_value2);
}
```

The dac function works perfectly, until I enable the thread `TSK_AdcSensor`.
The dac output will then give nonsense values.

By process of elimination I have found that commenting:

```
// ADC1_Configuration();
// ADC3_Configuration();
```

and

```
//Start ADC1software conversion
//  ADC_SoftwareStartConvCmd(ADC1,ENABLE);

//Start ADC3 softwareconversion
//  ADC_SoftwareStartConvCmd(ADC3, ENABLE);
```

Allow the dac to work as normal. But I cannot see why?

The `printf` after I set the DAC channel shows the correct value, but the voltage reading at the output does not correspond.

Anyone have any idea's?

DAC Config

```
  void DAC_Configuration(void)
{
    DAC_InitTypeDef DAC_InitStructure;


    dac_GPIO();
    dac_RCC();

    //DAC channel1 Configuration (Digital Regulator 2)
    DAC_InitStructure.DAC_Trigger = DAC_Trigger_Software;
    DAC_InitStructure.DAC_WaveGeneration = DAC_WaveGeneration_None;
    DAC_InitStructure.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OutputBuffer_Disable;
    DAC_Init(DAC_Channel_1, &DAC_InitStructure); 

    //DAC channel2 Configuration (Digital Regulator 1)
    DAC_InitStructure.DAC_Trigger = DAC_Trigger_Software;
    DAC_InitStructure.DAC_WaveGeneration = DAC_WaveGeneration_None;
    DAC_InitStructure.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OutputBuffer_Disable;
    DAC_Init(DAC_Channel_2, &DAC_InitStructure); 

//  // Enable DAC Channel1 reg 2
    DAC_Cmd(DAC_Channel_1, ENABLE);
    // Enable DAC Channel2 reg 1
    DAC_Cmd(DAC_Channel_2, ENABLE); 

  // Set default analog output as zero */
  DAC_SetChannel2Data(DAC_Align_12b_R, 0x0000);  // PA5 
    //  // Set default analog output as zero */
  DAC_SetChannel1Data(DAC_Align_12b_R, 0x0000);  // PA4     
}
```

Comment: A quick scan of a couple of STM32F103 datasheets suggests the DAC outputs share pins with some ADC1 inputs - is that the case on the part you're using?

Comment: STM32F103ZET6
That would make sense but the DAC pins are PA4 and PA5 and I definitely don't have them double defined as ADC1 inputs. I only use PA0, PA1, PA2, PA3, PA6 and PA7 from GPIOA on ADC1

Comment: Ok, when I disable one of the DAC channels config the other will work. This works both ways. , I have added the DAC_Configuration()